# Postdoc speculative application

Tags: postdocs, job-search, early-career

I am just about to finish my PhD and a prof I know well and I were discussing future postdoc labs. They suggested I email a friend of theirs in the US. I got a very positive reply saying my research experience and interest are perfect for them and they will have funding for a postdoc. They then said to give them a few days to find out when they will have the money and if I can be flexible about when I could start. I replied yes I can be flexible. It’s been two weeks and he has not got back to me with the interview date and when they will have the money as they promised.

Should I be worried or does things like this take time? I have another interview lined up hence why I am curious as to know when I should expect to hear from them.

Comment: Patience is a virtue... They have lots of things to do - may even be holiday season...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be worried or does things like this take time?

No, it often takes much longer than two weeks to organize a postdoc job.  Remind them every three weeks, and be patient.